# QNetworkAccessManager connected to 2 reply slots, how do I know which reply belongs to which request

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkrequest

I have 1 `QNetworkAccessManager` in my application and I am making 2 requests at the same time. When I get the reply back from the manager the replies are not in the order I called them and that makes sense. How can I work around that? Should I have another manager to weed out any request queues issues?

```
QNetworkRequest request1(ONE_GET);
request1.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
request1.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");  
m_nam.get(request1);

connect(&m_nam, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,this , &HelperClass::onReply1Recieved);

QNetworkRequest request2(TWO_GET);
request2.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
request2.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");

m_nam.get(request2);

connect(&m_nam, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,this , &HelperClass::onReply2Recieved);
```

Comment: it's a different slot

Comment: okay, sorry. Do you want the second petition to start when the first one ends?

Comment: I can handle it like that by signaling the first to quick off the second inside `onReply1REceived()` but I thought it's not clean

Comment: You did not answer me, from what I understand you want to start the first request, when you finish the first request you just want to be called the second request, that is to say they are in line, am I correct?

Comment: I just tried that (calling 2 when 1 finishes) and it actually solved an issue I was having with JSON data not coming inside the reply, I wonder why hmmm

Comment: I wanted to request both and read the data as they come, but apparently that creates issues

Comment: I will check it out, I was disconnecting the signal inside the beginning of each of the replies though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your case is that both slots are connecting to the same signal so both will be notified and even if you try to disconnect the signal that does not guarantee that it works correctly, the solution is to connect the signal of each of the `QNetworkReply`:

```
QNetworkRequest request1(ONE_GET);
request1.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
request1.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");  
QNetworkReply *reply1 = m_nam.get(request1);
connect(reply1, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HelperClass::onReply1Recieved);


QNetworkRequest request2(TWO_GET);
request2.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
request2.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");
QNetworkReply *reply2 = m_nam.get(request2);
connect(reply2, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HelperClass::onReply2Recieved);
```

---

```
void HelperClass::onReply1Recieved(){
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}

void HelperClass::onReply2Recieved(){
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: nice! the replies are unique so the signals are individually called. makes sense. Thanks!